# 犬の質問 Why is my answer incorrect? What does ご家族にちょっと聞いてもらえないかな。 mean?

Tags: meaning

> 女: あ、一ヶ月海外出張に行かれるんでしたね。
>
> 男: そうなんだよ。一か月もペットホテルじゃかわいそうだし、君のうち、家族みんな犬が好きだって言ってたから・・・・。餌や犬のベッドなんかは、僕がちゃんと持っていくから、ご家族にちょっと聞いてもらえないかな。
>
> 男の人は女の人に何を頼んでいますか。
>
> 1. 犬をもらって欲しい
> 2. 犬を預かって欲しい
> 3. 犬の世話に来て欲しい
> 4. 犬をペットホテルに連れて行って欲しい

I chose 3 and it was wrong, why was 3 wrong and why is 2 correct?
What does the ご家族にちょっと聞いてもらえないかな mean at the end, why is he asking the girl to go to his parents and ask them what?  Or is he talking to himself saying he will go and talk to his parents?
What does ご家族にちょっと聞いてもらえないかな。 mean?

Comment: It would make it easier for people to help you if you explained why you thought 3 was correct and 2 was wrong.

Comment: @Leebo Well I dont understand what he means by this: ご家族にちょっと聞いてもらえないかな  Is he saying to the girl to go talk to his parents?  What for?

Answer (score 2):

3 means that the woman will come to the man's house take care of the dog.
2 means to take care of the dog in the woman's own house.
3 is wrong, 2 is correct because the woman was asked to care for the dog in her own house.

Comment: what does ご家族にちょっと聞いてもらえないかな mean?

Comment: @fynxgloire it means "could you ask your family?"